# Removing an action declared inside a function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on my game and I'm stuck in removing an action.
I have a set of pipes that move from right to the left forever (like flappy bird).
I created the pipes inside a function, and the action of moving them inside `didMoveToView`. So, inside the pipe function I create the pipes and run the action.
(I simplified the code)

```
func initPipes() {
    let pipePair = SKNode()
    pipePair.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + 70, y: 0)
    //PIPE 1
    let pipe1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(70, 700))

    //here i set physics and position

    pipePair.addChild(pipe1)

    //PIPE 2
    let pipe2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(70, 700))

    //same as pipe1

    pipePair.addChild(pipe2)

    //SCORE
    let scoreSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 150))

    pipePair.addChild(scoreSprite)

    pipePair.runAction(moveAndRemove, withKey: "move")
    pipes.addChild(pipePair)

}
```

When a collision is detected I run a `gameOver` function. Inside this function if i write:

```
removeActionForKey("move")
```

the pipes continue to move. Maybe because I have to write `pipePair.removeActionForKey("move")`. But since `pipePair` is local i can't do it. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Is "pipes" node (pipePair parent node) defined as a property ?

Comment: Sorry i forget it. I declared it inside GameScene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a name to a `pipePair` node:

```
pipePair.name = "pipePair"
```

Then you can stop "move" action inside `gameOver` method like this:

```
let pipePair = pipes.childNodeWithName("pipePair")

if(pipePair.actionForKey("move") != nil){


     pipePair.removeActionForKey("move")
}
```

I guess this would be one way to do it.

Comment: It is untested, but that's how you can do it. Let me open up a Xcode. In the meanwhile , can you be more specific about what doesn't work ? Do you get any error, or just action is not removed ? Are you sure that you have named properly pipePair node ?

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it helped :) And as I said, it's untested, but that's the way you can do it and the whole point is to search node by name, so you can remove an action from the node which runs it. Removing an action on scene has no effect if you have started the action on pipePair node.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a bool variable to detect inside of update if the game was lost.

```
class GameScene: SKScene { 
var lost = false

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

if lost {

removeActionForKey("move")

}
}

func loseGame() {
lost = true

}
```

when the user replays the game you'll have to reset lost to false so you can detect when the user actually loses the game again

Comment: It's the same. The problem is that i have to write pipePair.removeActionForKey("move") since it's a pipePair action. But pipePair is local and i can't declare it outside. I can't even create the pipePair node outside because the game won't work. So i have to let it local...